# SQL - Format US Postal Codes that have 4 digit extension into parent zip code (group them)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, zip

Using **SQL** or **T-SQL**, in a column containing US postal zip codes, how can I group US postal codes that have 4 digit extension into their respective parent group(s)?

For example, zip codes of 84047-2345, 84047-6789 would be grouped into 84047.

Comment: yes you can. You need to `group by SUBSTRING(zipcode, 1, 5)`

Comment: Or `group by Left( ZIPcode, 5 )`.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Data Set:
Count Zip
1134 84047
45 84047
32 84047 

If the first number represents count, and the second number the zip code, how do I aggregate the counts so that all counts fall under the zip code of 84047?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to count them:

```
select left(zipcode, 5), count(*)
from t
group by left(zipcode, 5);
```

That would seem to do what you specify.

Comment: If the zip code represents Column A, and I have other values on the corresponding Column B, it's still not aggregating all the values under Column A such that I don't have counts in two separate similar zip codes. I need to have only one parent zip code, and all counts summed up under it.

Comment: @BenJaminSila . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear description of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Data Set: 
1134 84047
45 84047
32 84047 

If the first number represents count, and the second number the zip code, how do I aggregate the counts so that all counts fall under the zip code of 84047?

Answer (score 0):

select SUBSTRING(zip,1,5) from zip_table

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to list them without aggregating

```
SELECT distinct Left(zip,5) From Zip_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use and it works great!  This will give zipcode like this:  12345-1234.  If there's no last 4 digits, then it just gives the first 5 digits.

```
'ZipCode'       = case LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(zipcode)))
                            when 9 then
                            STUFF(zipcode, 6, 0, '-') 
                            else zipcode
                            end
```